# KnockoutJS or Javascript not keeping proper track of displayed array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, knockout.js

I'm writing a paginated table with a page selector at the bottom that displays the different page numbers

[image]

I'm using knockout.  The numbers are coming from a ko.computed array (*self.pages*) that calculates how many pages there are based on the number of results / results per page.  The problem I'm running into is if the data array is very long and the results per page is set somewhat low, I get something like this:

[image]

What I want to do is limit the number of menu items to three, so if page #4 is selected, only items 3,4,5 are visible.  Currently I'm implementing a second ko.computed that first retrieves the value of `self.pages`, then gets the value of the current page number (`self.pageNumber`), and slices the array so that only 3 items are returned:

```
self.availablePages = ko.computed(function() {
  var pages = self.pages();
  var current = self.pageNumber();
  if (current === 0) {
    return pages.slice(current, current + 3);
  } else {
    return pages.slice(current - 1, current + 2);
  }
});
```

Now all of this seems to be working fine but there's one bug I have not been able to stamp out. Using the knockout `css` data-bind, I'm telling it to assign a class of '*selected*' to whichever element holds the same value as `self.pageNumber` (see code below).

If the element selected does not require `self.availablePages` to change (i.e. selecting 2 when 1 was the previous selection), there are no problems; 2 becomes selected and 1 becomes un-selected.

However, if the selection does require `self.availablePages` to change (i.e. 1,2,3 visible, selecting 3 will change visible to 2,3,4), the correct numbers display, but instead of 3 being selected, 4 is selected. I'm assuming this is because the index of the array that 3 used to be located at (last) is now being occupied by 4.

Here's the menu:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: availablePages">
  <li data-bind="if: $index() < 1">
    <a data-bind="click: $parent.toFirstPage">First</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-bind="text: displayValue, click: $parent.goToPage(iterator), css: { selected: $parent.pageNumber() === iterator }"></a>
  </li>
  <li data-bind="if: $parent.isLastIteration($index)">
    <a data-bind="click: $parent.toLastPage">Last</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The array being iterated over was originally just an array of numbers, but in trying to fix this bug I changed it to be an array of the following object:

```
available.MenuModel = function(iterator) {
    var self = this;
    self.displayValue = iterator + 1;
    self.iterator = iterator;
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
}
```

One thing I tried doing was adding the `self.isSelected` observable to all items in the menu, and then when `self.availablePages` gets re-computed, the function checks what the pageNumber is and then finds which item in the array matches that and sets `self.isSelected(true)`, and then tried keying the css binding to that.

Unfortunately this did not work; it still has the exact same bug. I've been debugging the script like crazy and there doesn't seem to be an issue; everything seems to know that 3 should be selected, but what's actually selected is 4.

I'm guessing that the knockout bindings aren't smart enough to keep up with this. Is there something I can do or some pattern that would help knockout keep track of which element should be selected? I even tried taking knockout out of it completely, and had a function in the script manually remove/add the '*selected*' class whenever `self.pageNumber` was changed and/or whenever `self.availablePages` changed but I still got the same issue, so maybe this isn't a knockout issue but something with javascript.

I've tried everything else I can think of; subscribing to various observables, promises, but like I said everything already knows what should be selected so additional checks and callbacks aren't altering anything nor eliminating the bug.

I'm hoping someone will either know the cause/solution of the bug or a smarter way to accomplish the task.  This is the `self.pages` that `self.availablePages` keys off of, in case that's helpful:

```
    self.pages = ko.computed(function() {
        var start = self.totalPages();
        var pages = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < start + 1; ++i)
            pages.push(new available.MenuModel(i));
        return pages;
    });
```

This is the entire javascript model (using requireJs):

```
    define(['underscore', 'knockout'], function(_, ko) {

var available = available || {};

available.DynamicResponsiveModel = function(isDataObservable, isPaginated) {
        var self = this;
        self.workingArray = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.backgroundArray = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.pageNumber = ko.observable(0);
        self.count = function () {
            return 15;
        }
    self.resultsPerPage = ko.observable(self.count());
    self.selectResultsPerPage = [25, 50, 100, 200, 500];
    self.resultsPerPageOptions = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.selectResultsPerPage;
    });

    self.activeSortFunction = isDataObservable ? available.sortAlphaNumericObservable : available.sortAlphaNumeric;

    self.resetPageNumber = function() {
        self.pageNumber(0);
    }

    self.initialize = function(data) {
        var sortedList = data.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
            return obj2.NumberOfServices - obj1.NumberOfServices;
        });
        self.workingArray(sortedList);
        self.backgroundArray(sortedList);
        self.pageNumber(0);
    }

    self.intializeWithoutSort = function(data) {
        self.workingArray(data);
        self.backgroundArray(data);
        self.pageNumber(0);
    }

    self.totalPages = ko.computed(function() {
        var num = Math.floor(self.workingArray().length / self.resultsPerPage());
        num += self.workingArray().length % self.resultsPerPage() > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        return num - 1;
    });

    self.paginated = ko.computed(function () {
        if (isPaginated) {
            var first = self.pageNumber() * self.resultsPerPage();
            return self.workingArray.slice(first, first + self.resultsPerPage());
        } else {
            return self.workingArray();
        }
    });

    self.pages = ko.computed(function() {
        var start = self.totalPages();
        var pages = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < start + 1; ++i)
            pages.push(new available.MenuModel(i));
        return pages;
    });

    self.availablePages = ko.computed(function() {
        var pages = self.pages();
        var current = self.pageNumber();
        if (current === 0) {
            return pages.slice(current, current + 3);
        } else {
            return pages.slice(current - 1, current + 2);
        }
    });

            self.pageNumDisplay = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.pageNumber() + 1;
    });

    self.hasPrevious = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.pageNumber() !== 0;
    });

    self.hasNext = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.pageNumber() !== self.totalPages();
    });

    self.next = function() {
        if (self.pageNumber() < self.totalPages()) {
            self.pageNumber(self.pageNumber() + 1);
        }
    }

    self.previous = function() {
        if (self.pageNumber() != 0) {
            self.pageNumber(self.pageNumber() - 1);
        }
    }

    self.toFirstPage = function() {
        self.pageNumber(0);
    }

    self.toLastPage = function() {
        self.pageNumber(self.totalPages());
    }

    self.setPage = function(data) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            self.pageNumber(data);
        });
    }

    self.goToPage = function(data) {
        self.pageNumber(data);
    }

    self.isLastIteration = function (index) {
        var currentIndex = index();
        var count = self.pages().length;

        return currentIndex === count - 1;
    }

    self.resultsPerPage.subscribe(function() {
        self.pageNumber(0);
    });

    self.filterResults = function (filterFunction) {
        self.resetPageNumber();
        self.workingArray(filterFunction(self.backgroundArray()));
    }

    self.resetDisplayData = function() {
        self.workingArray(self.backgroundArray());
    }

    self.updateVisibleResults = function(data) {
        self.workingArray(data);
    }       
}

available.sortAlphaNumericObservable = function () {
    //...
}

available.sortAlphaNumeric = function () {
    //...
}

return available;
});
```

Here's the entire table:

```
<div data-bind="visible: showListOfEquipment, with: availableEquipmentModel">
<section class="panel panel-default table-dynamic">
    <table class="primary-table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div class="th">
                        Part Number    
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-up" data-bind="click: function () { sortByFirstColumn(false); }"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-down" data-bind="click: function () { sortByFirstColumn(true); }"></span>
                    </div>

                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="th">
                        Serial Number
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-up" data-bind="click: function () { sortBySecondColumn(false); }"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-down" data-bind="click: function () { sortBySecondColumn(true); }"></span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="th">
                        Type
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-up" data-bind="click: function () { sortByThirdColumn(false); }"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-down" data-bind="click: function () { sortByThirdColumn(true); }"></span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="th">
                        Equipment Group
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-up" data-bind="click: function () { sortByFourthColumn(false); }"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-down" data-bind="click: function () { sortByFourthColumn(true); }"></span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="th">
                        Operational
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-up" data-bind="click: function () { sortByFifthColumn(false); }"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-down" data-bind="click: function () { sortByFifthColumn(true); }"></span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="th">
                        Valid
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-up" data-bind="click: function () { sortBySixthColumn(false); }"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-down" data-bind="click: function () { sortBySixthColumn(true); }"></span>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: paginated">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.PartNumber"></td>
                <td><a target="_blank" data-bind="text: $data.SerialNumber, click: function () { $root.setSerialNumberAndFindEquipment(SerialNumber) }" style="color:royalblue"></a></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.Type"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.EquipmentGroup"></td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="css: $root.operationalCss($data), text: $root.getOpStatus($data)"></span>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.Validity"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <footer class="table-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 page-num-info">
                <span>Show <select style="min-width: 40px; max-width: 50px;" data-bind="options: selectResultsPerPage, value: resultsPerPage"></select> entries per page</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right pagination-container">
                <ul class="pagination-sm pagination" data-bind="foreach: pages">
                    <li data-bind="if: $index() < 1"><a data-bind="click: $parent.toFirstPage">First</a> </li>
                    <li class="paginationLi"><a data-bind="text: displayValue, click: $parent.goToPage(iterator), css: { selected: isSelected }"></a></li>
                    <li data-bind="if: $parent.isLastIteration($index)"> <a data-bind="click: $parent.toLastPage">Last</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you please post a complete, runnable example of your current pagination code, preferably as either a [Stackoverflow snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in your question or a JSFiddle?

Comment: I don't know how to get data in so not sure how to get it runnable, but I'll add the whole model and table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and built a paginator. Instead of using an array as you did, I used just the number of available pages, `pageCount`.

Probably the only thing worth looking into in more detail is the calculation which pages are to be displayed:

```
this.visiblePages = ko.computed(function() {
  var previousHalf = Math.floor( (this.visiblePageCount() - 1) / 2 ),
      nextHalf     = Math.ceil( (this.visiblePageCount() - 1) / 2 ),
      visiblePages = [],
      firstPage,
      lastPage;

  // too close to the beginning
  if ( this.currentPage() - previousHalf < 1 ) {
    firstPage = 1;
    lastPage  = this.visiblePageCount();

    if ( lastPage > this.pageCount() ) {
      lastPage = this.pageCount();
    }

  // too close to the end
  } else if ( this.currentPage() + nextHalf > this.pageCount() ) {
    lastPage  = this.pageCount();
    firstPage = this.pageCount() - this.visiblePageCount() + 1;

    if (firstPage < 1) {
      firstPage = 1;
    }

  // just right
  } else {
    firstPage = this.currentPage() - previousHalf;
    lastPage  = this.currentPage() + nextHalf;
  }

  for (var i = firstPage; i <= lastPage; i++) {
    visiblePages.push(i);
  }

  return visiblePages;

}, this);
```

Let's go through this piece by piece. We want our current page to be in the middle of all displayed pagination buttons, with some to its left and some to its right. But how many?

If we use an odd number such as three, that's simple: the number minus 1 (the selected one) divided by two. `(3 - 1) / 2 = 1`, or one to each side.

With an even number of pagination buttons to display, that doesn't work, so we calculate each side individually and round one result up and one result down:

```
var previousHalf = Math.floor( (this.visiblePageCount() - 1) / 2 ),
    nextHalf     = Math.ceil( (this.visiblePageCount() - 1) / 2 ),
```

There are three possible results:

1. our selection fits
2. we're too close to the beginning
3. we're too close to the end

If we're too close to the beginning:

```
if ( this.currentPage() - previousHalf < 1 ) {
  firstPage = 1;
  lastPage  = this.visiblePageCount();

  if ( lastPage > this.pageCount() ) {
    lastPage = this.pageCount();
  }

}
```

we start with 1 and try to display pages 1 up to `visiblePageCount`. If that doesn't work either, because we don't have enough pages, we simply display all we have.

If we're too close to the end:

```
  } else if ( this.currentPage() + nextHalf > this.pageCount() ) {
    lastPage  = this.pageCount();
    firstPage = this.pageCount() - this.visiblePageCount() + 1;

    if (firstPage < 1) {
      firstPage = 1;
    }
  }
```

we end with the last page and try to display as many as we need to the left. If that doesn't work, because we don't have enough pages, we simply display all we have.

Here's the full example:

```js
var ViewModel;

ViewModel = function ViewModel() {
  var that = this;
  
  this.pageCount        = ko.observable(20);
  this.currentPage      = ko.observable(1);
  this.visiblePageCount = ko.observable(3);
  
  this.gotoPage = function gotoPage(page) {
    that.currentPage(page);
  };
  
  this.visiblePages = ko.computed(function() {
    var previousHalf = Math.floor( (this.visiblePageCount() - 1) / 2 ),
        nextHalf     = Math.ceil( (this.visiblePageCount() - 1) / 2 ),
        visiblePages = [],
        firstPage,
        lastPage;
    
    if ( this.currentPage() - previousHalf < 1 ) {
      firstPage = 1;
      lastPage  = this.visiblePageCount();
      
      if ( lastPage > this.pageCount() ) {
        lastPage = this.pageCount();
      }
      
    } else if ( this.currentPage() + nextHalf > this.pageCount() ) {
      lastPage  = this.pageCount();
      firstPage = this.pageCount() - this.visiblePageCount() + 1;
      
      if (firstPage < 1) {
        firstPage = 1;
      }
      
    } else {
      firstPage = this.currentPage() - previousHalf;
      lastPage  = this.currentPage() + nextHalf;
    }
    
    for (var i = firstPage; i <= lastPage; i++) {
      visiblePages.push(i);
    }
    
    return visiblePages;
    
  }, this);
  
};

ko.applyBindings( new ViewModel() );
```

```css
ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
 -webkit-box-flex: 0;
 -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
     -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
         flex: 0 0 auto;
}

button {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: none;
}

button.selected {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><button data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, 1)">First</button></li>
  <!-- ko foreach: visiblePages -->
    <li>
      <button data-bind="text: $data,
                         click: $parent.gotoPage,
                         css: { selected: $parent.currentPage() === $data }"></button>
    </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <li><button data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, pageCount())">Last</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help.  I implemented the changes and it worked; wish I understood better what the issue was though; I was running into problems with page 0 using your model and trying to fix that caused the same issue with the smallest of changes by keying everything including visiblePages off of a new computed that was currentPage + 1.  So instead I changed the data-bind = text: $data + 1 and that worked... it just seems weird that the whole thing goes haywire when another computed is involved.  Both cases set the lowest accepted value to 0 and set first to 0... strange.

Comment: All comparisons assume page 1 to be the first one. I'll make a quick adaptation to a zero-based index, give me a minute.

Comment: Actually, scratch that: the code remains a lot more understandable if you go the other way around, leave the pagination as it is and simply compute `currentPage() - 1` for whatever other purpose you need (AJAX call?).