# Pagination using knockout

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am able to bind JSON data as follows:

### My json file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var jsondata = JSON.parse(var1);
    DisplayFields = function (jsondata) {
        var viewModel = {
            d: ko.observableArray(jsondata),
            pageSize: ko.observable(10),
            pageIndex: ko.observable(0),
            previousPage: function () {
                this.pageIndex(this.pageIndex() - 1);
            },
            nextPage: function () {
                this.pageIndex(this.pageIndex() + 1);
            }
        };
        viewModel.maxPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            return Math.ceil(this.d().length / this.pageSize()) - 1;
        }, viewModel);
        viewModel.pagedRows = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var size = this.pageSize();
            var start = this.pageIndex() * size;
            return this.d().slice(start, start + size);
        }, viewModel);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("Datasection"));
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("prevnext"));
    };
    DisplayFields(jsondata);    
});
```

### My HTML file

```
    <section class="col-lg-12 paddingBottom40 paddingTop20 RecentInnovation" id="Datasection" data-bind='template: { foreach: pagedRows }'>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-4">
                <div class="bgOrange blue text-center paddingTop10 paddingBottom10">
                    <span class="size18" data-bind="text: Views"></span>
                    <br>
                    View
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: '../SitePages/IdeaDetails.aspx?ideaid=' + ID }" class="size14 green"><strong><span data-bind="    text: BusinessProblem"></span></strong></a>
                <br>
                <p class="paddingTop5">Category:<span data-bind="text: InnovationType" class="green"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Submitted by: <span data-bind="    text: Requester" class="green"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;On <span data-bind="    text: Created " class="green"></span></p>
                <p class="paddingTop5">Tags: <span data-bind="text: Keywords" class="green"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;Domain: <span data-bind="    text: Domain" class="green"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;SubDomain: <span data-bind="    text: SubDomain" class="green"></span></p>
            </section>
            <section class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-right"><span data-bind="text: Status"></span><span data-bind="    css: statusCss"></span></section>
        </div>

    </section>
```

I want to add pagination(1,2,3,4...10,11) into my page with pages link so that user can go straight to any page. How to modify above javascript code to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29422899/100342

Comment: possible duplicate of [KnockoutJS or Javascript not keeping proper track of displayed array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420509/knockoutjs-or-javascript-not-keeping-proper-track-of-displayed-array)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<span data-bind="with: previousLink">
    <a data-bind="attr: { href: href }, click: $parent.sendPrevPage" title="Previous Page">Previous Page...</a>
</span>
<span data-bind="with: nextLink">
    <a data-bind="attr: { href: href }, click: $parent.sendNextPage" title="Next Page">Next Page...</a>
</span>
```

JS:

```
function LinkViewModel(model) {
    model = model || {};
    var self = this;
    self.href = model.Href || ' ';
    self.rel = model.Rel || ' ';
}

executeLink = function (linkVm) {
    $.ajax({
        url: linkVm.href,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            //do stuff
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
}

self.sendPrevPage = function () {
    executeLink(self.previousLink());
};

self.sendNextPage = function () {
    executeLink(self.nextLink());
};
```

Comment: This was not my requirement. I am already having "previous" and "next" link. I need to have page number link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super simplified example:

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: pageNumbers">
    <a data-bind="click: $root.gotoPage, text: pageNumber"></a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.maxPageIndex = ko.observable(10);
    self.pageNumbers = ko.computed(function() {
        var pages = [];
        for (i=1; i<=self.maxPageIndex(); i++){
            pages.push({pageNumber: i});
        }
        return pages;
    });
    self.gotoPage = function(page){
        console.log("Go to page " + page.pageNumber);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Note that knockout passes in the scoped object (in this case the 'page') into the click function. You don't need to wire anything  up, just call the click function from the $root and it will pass in the object from the scope of the for loop... I think that's cool, but I'm a dork that way.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/jp6hu5ho/

Comment: where is page number click event. href: 'pager?pageid=' + pageNumber is not working.

Comment: You've given us no idea of how to get to the 'next page'... you'll have to figure that out yourself. I've given you a construct for taking the min/max page and listing all the pages using knockout.